# Change the Hibernate database schema at run time in spring boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have A requirement where the current schema to be used is stored in db table;(`schema_a` or `schema_b`).

The application is loaded with default schema

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema_a
```

Now when the data in table is updated to `B` I want to consider all jpa query to use `schema_b` without any down time at server.

Comment: Hi Riddhi, were you able to solve your problem? I am looking for a solution for the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough to provide some code to your question, but you can catch inspiration from the following articles:
https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

[Spring Boot - Change connection dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935382/spring-boot-change-connection-dynamically?rq=1)

Comment: we have tried Following.  1. changing the datasource at runtime based on the schema.  2.setting the schema for for sql connection    but Hibernate jpa query doesnt use that schema I think it can be related to session factory which hibernate uses