# How to select a database in run time using spring boot

Tags: database

I have created an application with 2 databases. I need to select one of them in run time. Is there any method or class in spring boot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide some examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - Change connection dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935382/spring-boot-change-connection-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using application.properties configurations. You don't need to restart the server for those configurations to act.

Please refer to: 
    https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Drive
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html