# Spring Boot App That Uses Different DB Connections Per User

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Which would be the approach or overview idea to be able to let a user switch a DB Connection on runtime ?... For example: User X1 logs into the app and decide he wants to see data from USA environment or another... this would be for a QA environment... is this possible ?. I have a vague idea like disabling autoconfiguration for mongo (in this case) but nothing strong...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - Change connection dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935382/spring-boot-change-connection-dynamically)

Comment: Hi eol. Thankx for your answer... I managed to find the solution I wanted.

Comment: Hi eol. Thankx for your answer... I managed to find the solution I wanted... I need to have a bean that extend AbstractM9ngoConfiguration I think... And let it return a custom mongo db factory... This is the object that does the trick, because every time a mongorepository object executes any kind of operation, the app asks the db factory which should be the mongo client... So we could check which is the user logged and switch according to a certain criteria the mongo client returned... so different users may see different data in the same screen...