# Springboot application read from multiple datasources into a new database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating a new Springboot application and I want to achieve the following.

I need to have multiple datasources (different read-only databases) from which to read information from. 
That information that is collected I need to store it in a new different database.

Since the databases from where I obtain the data are read-only i do not intend to use Jpa or Hibernate.

But to store the actual newly generated object from the data obtained I would like to use Hibernate to make it easier for me.

I was able to read from multiple DataSources by doing the following.

First I created a **CustomerClient**:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomerClient {

    @Bean(name = "customerDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("stats-collector.clients.customers")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new CustomerRowMapper());
    }

    public static class CustomerRowMapper implements RowMapper<Customer> {
        @Override
        public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            return new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("name"), new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a **ProductClient**:

```
@Configuration
public class ProductClient {

    @Bean(name = "productDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("stats-collector.clients.products")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM product";

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ProductRowMapper());
    }

    public static class ProductRowMapper implements RowMapper<Product> {
        @Override
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            return new Product(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getDouble("price"), new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
    }
}
```

With this I was able to retrieve information from two different databases.
To try this out I created two services:

**CustomerStatsCollectorService**:

```
@Service
public class CustomerStatsCollectorService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerStatsCollectorService.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerClient customerClient;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void collectInformation() {
        List<Customer> customers = customerClient.getCustomers();
        logger.info("Collected information from customers database:: Customers fetched - {}", customers.size());
        customerRepository.saveAll(customers);
    }
}
```

**ProductStatsCollectorService**:

```
@Service
public class ProductStatsCollectorService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductStatsCollectorService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProductClient productClient;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void collectInformation() {
        List<Product> products = productClient.getProducts();
        logger.info("Collected information from products database :: Products fetched - {}", products.size());
        productRepository.saveAll(products);
    }
}
```

My model was done with the following:

**Customer**:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Timestamp timeCreated;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(Long id, String name, Timestamp timeCreated) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimeCreated() {
        return timeCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer {"
                + "id: " + id
                + ", name: " + name
                + "}";
    }
}
```

**Product**:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Double price;

    private Timestamp timeCreated;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Long id, String name, Double price, Timestamp timeCreated) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimeCreated() {
        return timeCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Target {"
                + "id: " + id
                + ", name: " + name
                + ", price: " + price
                + "}";
    }
}
```

And finally my two repositories:

**CustomerRepository**:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

**ProductRepository**:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

The main application had the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class StatsCollectorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StatsCollectorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My **application.yml** configuration file:

```
stats-collector:
  clients:
    customers:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customersDatabase
      username: postgres
      password:
    products:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/productsDatabase
      username: postgres
      password:

spring:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
    username: postgres
    password:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

After starting my application I get the following error:

> Field customerRepository in com.test.stats.collector.service.CustomerStatsCollectorService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
>   Action: 
>   Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
>   configuration. 
>   Process finished with exit code 1

The application was collecting the information from different datasources until I added the jpa and the repositories to store that data. I do not understand how to fix this since I only want to read objects from Products  database and Customers database and use Hibernate only for storing the data into a new database.

[My application structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MH8R.png)

Finally, my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>amc-stats-collector-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AMC Stats Collector</name>
    <description>AMC Stats Collector</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.amc</groupId>
        <artifactId>amc-stats-collector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46810611/3003337

Comment: Thanks both for the answer. Actually what I need is different. I need to read data from database A and database B into two objects (A and B). 
That data (A and B) must be store in a database C using Hibernate

Comment: So anyway you hv to create 3 DataSource and use corresponding repositories to fetch n merge and then persist..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using *CrudRepository* and this requires JPA compliant framework. You may be interested in [Spring Data JDBC](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Yes I DO want a JPA compliant framework. Only to store the data collected in the new database (**testdb**). I do not want a JPA compliant framework for the read-only databases

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem but I think you have to define two entity managers. https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/configuring-multiple-jpa-entity-managers-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks for the quick question again. I read the article and I understand now how to create two entity managers. What i do not understand is how to use it on my CrudRepository...

I think all the documentation from Springboot is incomplete regarding this